# My texture isn't being applied. My object remains grey. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: mesh

I import an .obj model fine (a church) and a .png texture created in Mesh lab. However when I apply the image as a texture, nothing happens. I switch to 'material' mode, but still nothing. I am wondering if I have to use a UV map, but I thought that the texture .png would be applied automatically given that it was exported with the Mesh from Mesh lab.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show your nodes and the render and texture and UV Map in a screen captures.  You may need to show the UV Map while the object is in edit mode with all vertices selected.

Comment: If you are experienced in UV Maps please state so.